# django haystack partial search for IntegerField

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Django-haystack 2.4.1. I am trying to do a partial search for `IntegerField`. I have a `item_id` filed in my searchindex. For example I want to search `23456`, `2345`, `234,` `23`, `2` all of these. This is not working with the query

`SearchQuerySet().filter(item_id__icontains=234).models(MyModel)`

Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 0):

In your `search_indexes.py` the field that is your document field, should be `EdgeNgramField`.

```
class ModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    indexed_text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

And obviously you should update the index every time before making queries.

Comment: Already I have a document field in my search_indexes.py like this `text = indexes.EdgeNgramFiled(document=True, use_template=True)`. Even making a query lik `SearchQuerySet().filter(text=234).models(MyModel)` doesn't work for me

Comment: Filtering with just the model is working. `Mymodel.objects.filter(id__icontains=234)` but not with the SearchQuerySet()`

Comment: Is item id in your indexes?

Comment: Yes. I have `item_id` in my index like this `item_id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='id', boost=2.10)`

Comment: Yeah. I am facing this issue and was trying from few days but no luck. Can you please let me know if you found anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145418/discussion-between-yashwanth-and-andrey-shipilov).